# Use the 4th isomorphism theorem to show the index formula

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and let $H \leq K \leq G$. Then show that $|G:H|=|G:K| \cdot |K:H|$. (no finiteness of $G$ is assumed). This is actually Thm 4.5 p. 39 in Hungerford. I was wondering if we could somehow use the (4th?) isomorphism theorem to show this easily. 
Any hints on how to go about this? or is this even possible?

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: A direct proof is probably the easiest. Let $h_1,\ldots,h_m$ and $k_1,\ldots,k_n$ be right coset reps of $H$ in $K$ and of $K$ in $G$, respectively. Prove that $\{h_ik_j \mid 1 \le i \le m,\, 1 \le j \le n \}$ is a set of right coset reps of $H$ in $G$. It's like the tower law for field extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Fact I: Given any group $G$ and a subgroup $H\subseteq G$, $[G:H]\cdot |H|=|G|$. This is proved by counting (and is true for arbitrary cardinalities).

Presumably, the fourth isomorphism theorem here means that $G/K\cong (G/H)/(K/H)$, provided the necessary normality conditions for the quotients *groups* to exist.

So now, using Fact I, and the definition of the quotient group:

$[G:K]\cdot [K:H]=|(G/H)/(K/H)|\cdot [K:H]=[G/H:K/H]\cdot [K:H]=[G/H:K/H]\cdot |K/H|=|G/H|=[G:H]$.

Note though that this proof relies of normality of the subgroups. The same result holds even without this requirement, and can be proven by counting. I don't see how to use the fourth isomorphism theorem to prove the general case though.

Another note: the isomorphism theorem used is somewhat more commonly referred to as the third isomorphism theorem. The fourth isomorphism theorem sometimes refers to what is known as the correspondence theorem.

Comment: Hm, I thought that the fourth isomorphism theorem is the so-called Zassenhaus lemma? Still thanks for the answer. And I thought that OP would like to use any isomorephism theorem, not restricted to the fourth?

Comment: Ittay Weiss thanks for your answer. @awllower: Well, the 4th isomorphism theorem is probably the one that would be useful. As for the name, I have never heard of Zassenhaus Lemma. In Dummit and Foote they call it the 4th Iso. Thm or the correspondence theorem as Ittay Weiss said.