# Given $H\triangleleft G, K\le G\ $, $\;K\nsubseteq H,\;$ and $(G:H) = p$, $\;p$ prime, prove $HK=G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose that $H\triangleleft G, K\le G\ $ and $K\nsubseteq H$. How we can prove that $HK=G?$

Also $(G:H)=p$ where p is prime.

Comment: What prevents $G = \{ 1,x,y,xy \}$ (Klein $V$ group), $H = \{ 1 \}$, and $K = \{ 1,x \}$?

Comment: That is very untrue. Need more hypotheses to conclude $HK=G$.

Comment: You are right, I have forgotten a hypothesis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With your modification, I give you a hint. By the index formula
$$p=(G:H)=(G:HK)(HK:H)$$
Since $p$ is prime, what can you say about the possibilities? Which one is impossible under the given assumptions?

Answer (score 2):

$K\nsubseteq H$, so there is a non-trivial element $k$ of $K$ such that $kH$
non-trivial in $G/H$. Since $(G:H)=p$, $G/H$ is cyclic, so this $kH$
generates $G/H$. So any element in $G$ can be written in the form $%
hk^{\alpha }$ (since $H$ normal in $G$) where $0\leq {\alpha }\leq p-1$ and $h\in H$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Show that $(G:H)=p$ implies $H$ is maximal.
- Show that $H\trianglelefteq G$ and $K\not\subseteq H$ imply $H\neq HK$.

Answer (score 1):

By [this formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/315546/use-the-4th-isomorphism-theorem-to-show-the-index-formula):
$$
[G : H] = [G : HK][HK : H]
$$

Since $[G : H] = p$ is prime, one of $[HK : H]$ and $[H : HK]$ must be $1$. It cannot be $[HK : H]$ because $K \not \subset H$ so $HK \ne H$. This forces $[G : HK] = 1$ and hence $G = HK$.